# Incorrect command when generating migration ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, migration

I am new to rails. I made an error when generating a db migration. I was trying to add avatar to restaurants. However I instead tried to add avatar to users.

This is the wrong command I entered:

```
rails g migration add_avatar_to_user avatar:string
```

However users does not exist it should be restaurants, so it should have been:

```
 rails g migration add_avatar_to_restaurant avatar:string
```

I tried to do rake db:migrate and then realized my error I got:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "avatar" varchar
```

I read some answers on stack overflow and they just said to run the correct generate migration and it will fix it. So I did but it did not.

So then I tried doing a rake db:rollback, which removed restaurants (This is the one I actually want to keep).

However I can see in my db/migrate folder I still have the migration where I created restaurant, the correct migration for adding avatar to restaurants and the the incorrect migration as per the picture below.

[image]

So before I mess it up any more I am wondering whether if I just delete the incorrect migration from the tree and run a rake db:migrate whether that will fix it or is there something else I should be doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rollback to your correct migration using,

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=2012342112
```

Make sure you use the version no you want to rollback to. In your case that is _create_restaurants.rb

Now delete the not necessary migration. `_add_avatar_to_users`

Then finally run `rake db:migrate`

At any given point you can check your migration status using

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.